# ruby how to create json with backslash in the value

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to create a json object in ruby that looks like this:

```
{
    "Envoy": {
        "Tags": "57:371BF172ED2AFA7\|",
        "SerialNumber": "55555555",
        "KernelVersion": "0123"
    }
}
```

So inside an irb I set the above json equal to an object like this:

```
json = {"Envoy":{"Tags":"57:371BF172ED2AFA7\|","SerialNumber":"55555555","KernelVersion":"0123"}
```

the result from irb is this:

```
=> {:Envoy=>{:Tags=>"57:371BF172ED2AFA7|", :SerialNumber=>"55555555", :KernelVersion=>"0123"}}
```

As you can see it got rid of the `\` in `"Tags"`
So then, I added another backslash in an attempt to escape the one that was being eaten. But the result added 2 backslashes instead of the expected 1 like this:

```
[59] pry(#<Object>)> json = {"Envoy":{"Tags":"57:371BF172ED2AFA7\\|","SerialNumber":"55555555","KernelVersion":"0123"}}
=> {:Envoy=>{:Tags=>"57:371BF172ED2AFA7\\|", :SerialNumber=>"55555555", :KernelVersion=>"0123"}}
```

As you can see I'm clearly lost, I need it to add one backslash in, so that when I do `json.to_json` it will add 2 backslashes instead of 4.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? I don't see any JSON or anything having anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 4):

The double backslash isn't actually in the string. It is just displayed that way in the console.

```
puts json[:Envoy][:Tags]
```

prints:

```
57:371BF172ED2AFA7\|
```

Note that the value you see as the return value in irb / rails console / etc is the same thing as calling `print some_object.inspect`, for example:

```
print "\\".inspect
```

prints:

```
"\\"
```